# venv Python uses incorrect sys.prefix

Tags: python, virtualenv, enthought

I am running canopy 64 bit Version: 1.0.3.1262 on mac Mountain Lion. I have installed virtualenv using easy_install. But while I am trying to execute the command:

```
virtualenv venv --distribute
```

It shows the following error:

```
Using base prefix '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents'
New python executable in venv/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
Referenced from: /Users/xxx/Desktop/untitled folder 2/venv/bin/python
Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/Users/xxx/Desktop/untitled folder 2' (should be u'/Users/xxx/Desktop/untitled folder 2/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Have any one had similar issue and solved it? Thank you in advance for valuable advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canopy uses `venv` instead of `virtualenv`

Try setting up your environment like so:

```
venv -s path/to/virtual_environment_dir
```

Taken from: https://support.enthought.com/entries/21802240-Use-venv-not-virtualenv-with-Canopy-Python

or if you want to set up an environment without the system site packages: [Setting up a virtural enviroment (venv) with no system site packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976993/setting-up-a-virtural-enviroment-venv-with-no-system-site-packages)

Comment: I fixed the problem. You need to specify the path of `venv` as well.

Comment: So the command should look like: `/Users/vessilli/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/venv flaskapp`

Comment: @vessilli venv should automatically point to that location, you shouldn't need to include the full path

Comment: May be, but in my case, it did not.