# Setting up a virtural enviroment (venv) with no system site packages

Tags: python, enthought, python-venv

I want to create a virtual environment using Enthought's Canopy distribution, but with no site packages.

following: https://support.enthought.com/entries/21802240-Use-venv-not-virtualenv-with-Canopy-Python

I set up the environment, leaving off the -s to not install the site packages:

```
$ venv path/to/virtual_environment_dir
$ source path/to/virtual_environment_dir/bin/activate
```

And this uses the correct python, but still uses the system `easy_install` and `pip`

```
(env) $ which python
path/to/virtual_environment_dir/bin/python
(env) $ which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
(env) $ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

So if I try to install anything, it just installs it globally.

Is there any way to install `pip` into the virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `setuptools` and `pip` manually into the environment. `venv` in Canopy is backported from the `venv` in Python 3, so unlike `virtualenv`, it has no special support for pre-installing these packages into the new environment. Just follow the standard installation instructions for [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions) and [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#installing-from-source) using the new environment's `python` executable.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Robert Kern's reply, I just keep having to look up the command so I'll post it here.

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py -O - | python
```